# C++, save two values in one

Tags: c++, class, stl

I previously read of a structure or class in C++11 that allows saving two values as one, what its name?

For example, I want to save 1 and 2 together, I know it's easy to implement but if there is one already done why to implement mine :)

Comment: Perhaps `std::pair<int,int>` or whatever types you want to store. They need not be the same.

Comment: And if you need more than two values, there's `std::tuple`.

Comment: If the values have the same type, there is also `std::array<int, 2>`.

Comment: @drescherjm right, are you aware of somewhere I can find implementation for something similar? like in

Comment: @smith [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is built into the language.

Comment: The header should have the implementation since its a template.

Comment: Why are you now asking to find an implementation, when the question says you'd prefer not to unless it is necessary? It is not necessary, just use `std::pair` or a `std::tuple`.

Comment: @smith are you asking for "something similar" because you can not use the containers that are already in the standard library?  There are very many types that can hold "two values".

Comment: You can even use custom type (which might allows proper naming for members).

Comment: the standard library offers lots of convenience stuff, sometimes but not always just search for what you want finds you the right thing. Try "C++ pair of values" (and "C++ two values" is also just two clicks away)

Comment: @Bathsheba why can't `memcpy` be implemented in standard C++? `for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) ((unsigned char*)dst)[i]=((unsigned char*)src)[i];`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Sorry I've left you hanging out there. I'll dig something out on this.

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP is perhaps unaware that C++ includes standard libraries -- that an "implementation" for all these mentioned types can be assumed to already exist?

Comment: @DrewDormann well, the question is tagged with [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl)

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of storing a number of values without naming them all is to use an array:

```cpp
int arr[2] = {1, 2};
```

C++ being what it is, you have lots of other ways to do that. You could achieve something similar with the use of `std::array`, `std::vector` (or other STL containers), `std::tuple`, `std::pair`, `new int[2]`, `struct {int x, y;} elms;`, or do something crazy like store 2 32bit values in a single 64bit integer. These are all suitable for different use cases depending on stuff like if the values you're trying to store have the same type, if you know how many of them you want to store at compile time, if the size is fixed, if you have a few of them or many of them, if you're trying to interface with C APIs and so on. I suggest you have a look at our [C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10147399).